# Query failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "msd@gmail.com" could not be bound

Tags: php, sql-server

Whenever I tried to update my table am getting this error.

My SQL file where I have update function has this code:

```
function updateUser($userid, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $email, $address, $zip, $city, $state, $password)
{
    $firstname = str_replace('\'', '\'\'', trim($firstname));
    $lastname = str_replace('\'', '\'\'', trim($lastname));
    $phone = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($phone));
     $email = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($email));
      $address = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($address));
       $zip = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($zip));
        $city = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($city));
         $state = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($state));
          $password = str_replace('\'', '\'\'',trim($password));


    $query = <<<STR
Update tbl_users
Set firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', phone = $phone, email = $email,
address = '$address', zip = '$zip', city = '$city', state = '$state', password = '$password'
Where userid = $userid
STR;

   executeQuery($query);
}
```

My profile page where am trying to update has the following code:

```
     if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            // get the details for the movie to be edited





       $userdetails = getUserDetailsByID($_SESSION['user_id']);

           $_SESSION['userdetails'] =  $userdetails;








    }

    $lastname = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['firstname'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['phone'];
    $email = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['email'];
    $address = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['address'];
    $zip = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['zip'];
    $city = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['city'];
    $state = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['state'];
    $password = $_SESSION['userdetails'][0]['password'];

    if (isset($_POST['register']) && count($userdetails)){

        updateUser((int)$_POST['userid'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['phone'],
                $_POST['email'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['zip'],$_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['password']);
        header("Location: profile.php");
            echo '<h2>Thank you for Registering.  You will now be redirected to the login page.<h2>';
            die();

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I know nothing about php but the error message suggests that the `$email` variable should be srrounded by `'`: , `email = '$email',`

Comment: It looks like you have some serious SQL injection security issues here. What driver are you using - PDO? You should be using parameter binding, not query string concatenation.